# How many distinct roots of $f(z) = z^6 + (10-i)z^4 + 1$ lie inside $(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How many distinct roots of $f(z) = z^6 + (10-i)z^4 + 1$ lie inside $(-1,1) \times(-1,1)$?

Thought's so far: By Rouché's Theorem, I can show that $f$ has four roots in the unit disk and four roots in the disk of radius $2$, so $f$ must have four roots in the given domain. But I'm not sure how to find out how many are distinct. Just a hint would be appreciated, as I'm trying to figure this out on my own as much as possible (it's an old qual problem).

Comment: If not all four zeros are distinct, then at least one of them is a common zero of $f$ and $f'$. The zeros of $f'$ are rather easy to determine.

Comment: To add to Daniel Fischer's answer, note that not all four zeros are the same either since if $z$ is a zero, $-z$ is a zero.

Comment: These roots are $$ 0.4092994449- 0.3834512119\,i,- 0.4092994449+ 0.3834512119\,i,-
 0.1575338048- 3.167728642\,i, $$   $$0.1575338048+ 3.167728642\,i,-
 0.3906567584- 0.4042475231\,i, 0.3906567584+ 0.4042475231\,i.
 $$